# could not fetch origin

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I have been trying to clone a branch without fetching other branches using this:

```
mkdir $BRANCH
cd $BRANCH
git init
git remote add -t $BRANCH -f origin $REMOTE_REPO
git checkout $BRANCH
```

But after I put my password I get the following error, the weird thing is this has worked in other branches

Updating origin

```
manuel@repoxxxxxx.com's password:
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/repoxxxxx/branchxxx
error: Could not fetch origin
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~/repoxxx/brancxxxx$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Git allows you to clone just one branch. Try using this command:

```
git clone -b $BRANCH --single-branch <git repo url>
```